# Vue Bind Click On Classes

Tags: vue.js

I am a newbie in Vue.js.

In old jQuery, it was simple to bind a click on some classes:

```
$('body').on('click','some-class-*', function(e) {})
```

Bu how to do it in Vue? I read that I can make a bind on a single element like

```
<span v-bind:click="dosomething" classes="some-class-1"></span>
```

Comment: The syntax for binding to events on a single element in Vue is `v-on:click="dosomething"` or `@click="dosomething"`. As far as I am aware, there's no way to listen for an event on all elements with a specific class natively in Vue.

Comment: Thanks. So in Vue we can't manipulate the DOM as in JQuery? It just adds reactivity?

Comment: That's correct for the most part.

Answer (score -1):

You can archive this with normal JS:

```
var mySelection = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');

for(var i = 0; i < blockSelection.length; i++) {
   (function(index) {
      mySelection[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
         // Do something
      })
   })(i);
}
```

Comment: I know. I would do it in Vue.

Comment: @gdm You can use this in Vue, it´s a JavaScript Framework. And in fact it is the only solution without using another lib. Always having fun to help people learn something new. You are welcome.